# Generic with a lower bounded wildcard <? super Dog>

Tags: java, generics, wildcard, bounded-wildcard

```
class Animal{}
class Dog extends Animal{}
class Cat extends Animal{}
public class Mixer<A extends Animal>{
    public <C extends Cat> Mixer<? super Dog> useMe(A a, C c){
        //return new Mixer<Object>();//KO
        return new Mixer<Animal>(); //OK
    }
}
```

The return parameter is `Mixer<? super Dog>` so if is a defined with a lower bounded wildcard

Why do I have a compiler error when I return a `Mixer<Object>` and there is no compiler error with `Mixer<Animal>`?

Comment: Can you re-phrase your question? Its not clear what you are asking.

Comment: @RohitJain : he says to return `Mixer<Animal>` is allowed but not `Mixer<Object>` why?

Comment: I already have the answer of the book but it doesn't clear my doubt.
It says that because return type of the method is Mixer<? super Dog>, which means a Mixer object with a generic type that is either a Dog or a supertype of Dog. But in this case Object is a supertype and there is a compiler error.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is not in the return type of your method, rather it is the `Generic Type` bound to your class `Mixer`.

**Let's see what went wrong: -**

```
public <C extends Cat> Mixer<? super Dog> useMe(A a, C c)
```

The return type **`Mixer<? super Dog>`** means, you can return any `Mixer` of type `Dog` or a `super-type` of Dog, may be `Animal`.

```
    //return new Mixer<Object>();//KO
    return new Mixer<Animal>(); //OK
```

So, both the `return` statments **would have worked fine**, because, both `Animal` and `Object` is a `super-type` of `Dog`.

**But**, **the reason why the `first one` does not fits** in is because, you have declared your class as: -

```
public class Mixer<A extends Animal>
```

So, you have `bound` your `type` that can be associated with `Mixer` class to either `Animal` or its `subtype`.
Now, since, `Object` is not a subtype of `Animal`, you can't just create: -

```
new Mixer<Object>();
```

So, you can create instances of your class like:-

```
new Mixer<Animal>(); // OR
new Mixer<Dog>();  // Dog extends Animal  // OR
new Mixer<Cat>();  // Cat extends Animal

// **** But NOT like this ******
new Mixer<Object>();  // Object does not extend Animal
```